# Changing Local Url

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, url

I'm starting a new project on my own and have a newbie question that I can't figure out.

Right now I'm creating an MVC project in Visual Studio using C# and Javascript.
When I run the solution locally it pops up as ip;

> Example: 111.0.0.2:7070

Although I'm trying to add different controllers like /secondpage etc..
I'm used to having it run like;

> localhost:7070/default

How do I change it to the latter?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

Assuming you are using the latest version of Visual Studio your best best is to:

1. Right click on your project
2. Select properties
3. Click "Web" on the left hand side
4. Under servers you can change the "Project Url" to "https://localhost:7070/"
5. Above that, under "Start Action", you can choose "Specific Page"
6. Set this to "default"

Your application should start as https://localhost:7070/default.

Also, you can change https to http if you aren't developing in https.

The other answer of updating your host file would also work as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you! That did it.

Answer (score 0):

if you windows , update system32/etc/host file.